# Logical operators in if-else in R

Tags: r, math, loops, logical-operators

I have the following table (5 columns and 3 rows) called mat :

```
AC CA RES
1   0  
2   2 
1   3 
0   0 
0   1
```

The operation being performed is `mat[1]/mat[1]+mat[2]`

I am testing for the following : 
1) If both columns of a row are zero, the result should be NA.
2) If only one column of a row is zero and the other has a non-zero number, proceed with calculation. (Even if the numerator is 0, that's okay)

I am currently using this if-else structure within a for-loop going row-wise:

```
if(mat[b,1]>=0|mat[b,2]>=0){mat[b,3]<-(mat[b,1]/(mat[b,1]+mat[b,2]));}
else{is.na(mat[b,3])=TRUE;}
```

I get the following error :

```
1: In Ops.factor(mat[b, 1], 0) : >= not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(mat[b, 2], 0) : >= not meaningful for factors
```

Is there a smoother way of doing this?

The numbers are always integer, and are always 0 or greater.
I would like to use `apply` but how do I directly assign the results of `apply` into the 3rd column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get result you don't need a for loop, just use `ifelse()`. This will work if columns in your data frame `mat` is numeric not the factors (as pointed out by @Arun in comment).

```
mat$RES<-ifelse(mat[,1]==0 & mat[,2]==0,NA,mat[,1]/(mat[,1]+mat[,2]))

 mat
  AC CA  RES
1  1  0 1.00
2  2  2 0.50
3  1  3 0.25
4  0  0   NA
5  0  1 0.00
```

Comment: nice, but still that's not the error. you'll have to do: `mat[] <- lapply(mat, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` to convert the columns to numeric from factor.

Comment: Putting both your responses together makes it work like a charm. Thank you both :)