# ifelse statement using logical condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, logical-operators, logical-or

I have this data frame

```
DF
ID    WORD_LIST   
1     APPLE
2     RED
3     SNOW
4     ANKARA
5     RENEW
```

I would like to select only word starting with "A" or "R"

```
DF
ID    WORD_LIST    WORDS_A_R  
1     APPLE        APPLE
2     RED          RED
3     SNOW         NA
4     ANKARA       ANKARA
5     RENEW        RENEW
```

I tried this code

`DF %>% mutate(WORDS_A_R  = ifelse(grepl("^A" | "^R", WORD_LIST), as.character(WORD_LIST), NA))`

But this error occurs

```
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Comment: `grepl("^A|^R", WORD_LIST)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085994/logical-operators-in-if-else-in-r.

Comment: revision status https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62834633/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
transform(df, WORDS_A_R  = ifelse(grepl("^[AR]", WORD_LIST), WORD_LIST, NA))
```

If you prefer `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(WORDS_A_R  = ifelse(grepl("^[AR]", WORD_LIST), WORD_LIST, NA))

#  ID WORD_LIST WORDS_A_R
#1  1     APPLE     APPLE
#2  2       RED       RED
#3  3      SNOW      <NA>
#4  4    ANKARA    ANKARA
#5  5     RENEW     RENEW
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `base R` with `substring()` function:

```
#Create condition
cond1 <- substr(DF$WORD_LIST,1,1)=='A' | substr(DF$WORD_LIST,1,1)=='R'
#Create var
DF$WORDS_A_R <- NA
DF$WORDS_A_R[cond1]<-DF$WORD_LIST[cond1]

ID WORD_LIST WORDS_A_R
1  1     APPLE     APPLE
2  2       RED       RED
3  3      SNOW      <NA>
4  4    ANKARA    ANKARA
5  5     RENEW     RENEW
```